# Pumping Lemma - Grammar - Regular language

Tags: regular-language, context-free-grammar, regular-expressions, pumping-lemma

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding this exercise:
Indicate whether the following grammar describes a regular language. Prove your answer.

> G4: $S \to aS|aSbS|ε$

My answer is using this regular expression: $L= \{a,ab\}^*$ therefore, the grammar describes a regular language;
The official solution says: Not regular. Use the pumping lemma and the string $(a^p)(b^p)$ and pump down. (where ^ means to the power of)

Can you help me understand why my regular expression doesn't work or why the pumping lemma proves the language is not regular?

Comment: The language contains, eg, the string $aabb$, which is not in your regex.

Comment: damn, I didn't even notice that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Turning my comment into an answer: your regex does not give that grammar, but the following grammar:
$$S \rightarrow aS \vert abS \vert \epsilon$$
This captures the iterative notion of the Kleene star; you can put either $a$ or $ab$, and at the end you can repeat that (or put nothing). Putting a string in the middle of the string (usually) cannot be expressed by just a Kleene star.

But as for proving it's not regular, note that any string in this grammar has at least as many $a$'s as $b$'s. The hint, then, tells you to pump the initial $a$ section down to get something for which this invariant does not hold. The exact argument requires just a bit of finagling with the specifics of the lemma.